# Yii2 api object not found when id field not named id

Tags: php, yii2

I have other apis working but I just added a table that has `user_id` as the id field instead of `id` and now the api says the object is not found. Is there a way to override the field the api looks for with `userinfos/1`?

Where the log will usually say this for `users/12`

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id`='12'
```

I get this error for `userinfos/12` because id is actually user_id in the user_info table:

```
exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Object not found: 12' in /opt/decathletics/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rest/Action.php:101
```

It should say `SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id='12'` but instead I get the above error

UserinfoController.php

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use Yii; 
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\User;
use api\modules\v1\models\UserInfo;

class UserinfoController extends ActiveController
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        ];
        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        return Yii::$app->user->id == Yii::$app->request->get('id');
                    },
                    'verbs' => ['GET','PUT']
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\UserInfo';

}
```

UserInfo.php model

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\models;

use Yii;


class UserInfo extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_info';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id'], 'required'],
            [['user_id'], 'integer'],
            ...

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            ...
        ];
    }


}
```

Comment: show the related models and controllers code

Comment: @scaisEdge ok I added the the model and controller

Comment: But the table you added It does not replace the management of the users only adds some fields?

Comment: @scaisEdge yes it is extra information about each user, user_id is a foreign key of id in the user table

Comment: Show also (the code)  how do you call the action

Comment: what do you mean by how do I call the action?

Comment: if you're referring to the view action, Yii does that automatically, so I have nothing modifying it currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ActiveController** will use `yii\rest\Action::findModel($id)` to get your data based on its model **primary key** as declared in the DB table. In your case you may try to check your database schema to see if `user_id` is really defined as Primary Key of the `user_info` table (and not `id` instead) or you can try to manually override your model's `primaryKey()` method by adding this :

```
class UserInfo extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  ...

  public static function primaryKey()
  {
     return ['user_id'];
  }

  ...
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error, and user_id is defined as the primary key in the db. I do not have an id column in this table

Comment: `getUser()` shouldn't return this instead : `return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);` ?

Comment: it should be the way it is because it is looking up id in the user table, but that piece doesn't matter, I have now deleted that from the code

Comment: steel not getting it. you log files says issue is when getting user (not user info) while the UserInfo model says it has one user on `this->id = user->user_id` which looks inversed to me. are you retrieving the related user within extraFileds or Fields ? why the issue in logs is with `user` instead of `user_info` ?

Comment: no I am only trying to get the fields from the user_info table.

Comment: I gave the user log as an example, it doesn't actually show up in the user_info one. the user_info gives the error. When I do the api for user it works

Comment: I edited the question to try and make that more clear

Comment: So i tried yours again and got an error saying can't override static, so I added static to the function and now it is trying this code `SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE u='12'`. I have no idea where the `u` is coming from

Comment: ok can you try to see what is the output of `UserInfo::primaryKey()` (before overriding it) ? maybe Yii is mistaking your model's primary key. also be sure that user_info with user_id='12' exist. also check how [this function in source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/cb7d29041645120e4eba28808920f5512fcd704e/framework/rest/Action.php#L80) works. that is the function throwing the 404 error.

Comment: So it looks like it is showing two fields as the primary key, but when I check in my database there is only one key. Is it because I have other tables that reference the non primary key column as a foreign key

Comment: when I use the code from your answer however it returns just `user_id`

Comment: I'm going to accept to answer and start a new question because it looks like a different issue with it trying to select the column u instead of what is the primary key

Comment: thanks ! i'm not sure about but it may also help if you export the DB sql code used to recreate that table and check if something is wrong with it

Comment: I'll have to see, but your primaryKey code help me figure out that something is making that extra column a primary key, so I wonder if it has something to do with that

Comment: @MichaelStClair can you to try to make the primaryKey() function return ['user_id'] instead of 'user_id' ? i'm not sure about as i cant test it right now but i think it should be an array instead of string. i'll check yii's docs any way and update my unswer

Comment: great ! we both worked on it ! we know then that it should be static + return an array !